# Constructor Syntax for Boolean Properties Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, constructor, boolean

Sorry if my wording is confusing in the title.  Basically, I have a Class File that I am instantiating with 7 arguments (2 Double and 5 Boolean)

Now I understand how the syntax for the double works:

```
Purchases = New Purchase(Double.Parse(SalesPriceTextBox.Text), Double.Parse(TradeTextBox.Text),
```

In my class file I have this property:

```
Property CheckBox1() As Boolean
    Get
        Return CheckBox1Boolean
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        If value = True Then
            CheckBox1Boolean = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

How do I set up this boolean property in my constructor.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same way as you did for the double, but instead use [boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
Boolean.Parse(value)
```